# c++ profiler that can attach to a running process?

Tags: c++, linux, performance, profiling

I have a program written in c++ that I want to profile, and I want to avoid restarting it when I start and stop profiling. Ideally I would be profiling both CPU usage and memory allocation. Is there any tool that will allow me to do this? I'm running on Linux.

Comment: Which platform are you on? Windows? Linux?

Answer (score 4):

### Free

1. [oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/news/)
2. [perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page)
3. [SystemTap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/) (probably want a RedHat/CentOS distro for this)

### Not Free

1. [VTune](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune/)

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be [Zoom from RotateRight](http://www.rotateright.com) - you can download a free 30 day evaluation from their web site.

Comment: ++ Yes, Zoom is a good tool for the performance part. I don't know about the memory part, but I usually find that if there is slowness due to excessive memory allocation, it shows up in performance tuning.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get by with simple metrics, in the past, I have implemented a simple profiler. Track memory and time. Track the start and stop of each function, print a line at the start and stop. Track the memory before and after if important. Have all of this gated by a runtime variable that you can change externally. In a web application, it could be an extra post/get parameter. In a thick client program, it could be an extra switch.

Then, at runtime, you could start to collect data. I have added multiple levels in the past as well to allow for selective and then more detailed data collection.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can try valgrind. It is a bundle of different modules put together into a neat package

Answer (score 0):

Add metrics to your code. Profile with gprof http://linuxgazette.tuwien.ac.at/100/vinayak.html.